# Modifying Elasticsearch index with Logstash output

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash

What I want is to append a sequence of characters to the default Elasticsearch index created by the corresponding Logstash output plugin. My output config looks like this:

```
 output {
    elasticsearch {
         hosts => "localhost:9200"
         index => "%{index}-1234"
    }
 }
```

However, what the plugin does is creating an index named '%{index}-1234'. My current approach is based on [this discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-could-i-set-index-type-at-logstash/985/3) and seems to work for others.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you end up with the literal value, it means that the variable was not set.  Either use an existing variable, or set "index" with mutate->add_field{}.

Comment: Setting 'index' directly and accessing it didn't work for any reasons, but I've build on your approach and created an additional field that holds my pre-built index. In the output plugin, I simply assign the temporal value to the index via index => "%{myField}" . This works like a charm. Thanks for your help =)